# Python: make new lists for all nested list items (level 1)

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a nested list (4 levels) and want to give out each list item (first level) as a new list. I know how to print this:

```
mynestedlist = [[([6, "x1a", "y1a"], [8, "x1b", "y1b"]), ([9, "x2a", "y2b"], [4, "x2b", "y2b"])],
            [([6, "x1a", "y1a"], [9, "x2a", "y2b"]), ([8, "x1b", "y1b"], [4, "x2b", "y2b"])],
            [([6, "x1a", "y1a"], [4, "x2b", "y2b"]), ([9, "x2a", "y2b"], [8, "x1b", "y1b"])]]


for i in range(0,len(mynestedlist)):
    print(i)
    print(mynestedlist[i])
```

But I want to give each item out as a new list. I can't do this because I do not know how to automatically change the name of the list so I don't overwrite my list in each loop.
I tried something like:

```
for i in range(0,len(mynestedlist)):
    "list"+str(i) = [mynestedlist[i]]
```

but this doesn't work (obviously, I guess). Probably an easy question but I can't solve it, please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary` here , dictionary with `"list + str(i)"` key and value is desired list :

```
myDic = {}
for key,value in enumerate(mynestedlist,1):
    myDic["list"+str(key)] = value
```

Result:

```
{'list3': [([6, 'x1a', 'y1a'], [4, 'x2b', 'y2b']), ([9, 'x2a', 'y2b'], [8, 'x1b', 'y1b'])], 'list1': [([6, 'x1a', 'y1a'], [8, 'x1b', 'y1b']), ([9, 'x2a', 'y2b'], [4, 'x2b', 'y2b'])], 'list2': [([6, 'x1a', 'y1a'], [9, 'x2a', 'y2b']), ([8, 'x1b', 'y1b'], [4, 'x2b', 'y2b'])]
```

For more information about dictionary visit here:

[Python Dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

Comment: I'd suggest to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of `range`.

Comment: thanks a lot! This works. Is it not possible however to produce lists, not a dict? Or would it be possible but this is the better way to go?

Comment: @ElenaWimmerwuchs , I'm not sure why you dont want use `Dict` because you can do any thing with it as list , list can't have names that you want

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the question correctly, you would like to identify the last nest and its index in your nested list. the solution that I can think of is not straight forward though worth learning about:

```
def lastnest(nest, level=0, c=0):
    level += 2
    counter = 0
    for j in nest:
        if any([type(x) == list or type(x) == tuple for x in j]):
            for i in j:
                c += 1
                if type(i) is list or type(i) is tuple:
                    lastnest(i, level=level, c=c)
        else:
            counter += 1
            print level, (c-1)%len(j), counter, j


lastnest(mynestedlist)
```

this should print out the level, nest id and nest item index as well as the list itself, but it does assume that all the last nests will be of the same `len()`